# error while passing null/empty string to GUID datatype from a php soap client

Tags: php, soap, client

I am using PHP to consume a ASP.NET webservice. This particular method requires a variable of GUID as a parameter. It is defined as Nullable.
I am trying to send a null or empty string "" as the parameter. Following which, i get a SoapFault exception: [a:DeserializationFailed] error.
Says that The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Guid'.'

Any idea as to how to pass a null or empty string as a parameter here.

Thanks in advance.

Aman

Comment: Provide code example of how you tried to send null value, please

Comment: $demoAccountRegistrationRequest->LoggedInAccountId = "";

Answer (score 2):

Try .NET's Guid.Empty value of "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}".  This may or may not work depending on the web service's implementation of filtering/searching etc.

Answer (score 1):

.NET doesn't do NULLs. What you've most likely done is found someone who wrote a .net web service and has made no error checks to detect data from other languages/systems than other .net applications. These problems are VERY hard to solve. But you can try tricking the service. Try sending other negative data. False, 0, and possibly, as odd as it sounds, " ". (I know, but it has worked for me in the past, go fig)

Answer (score 0):

In c# terms you may have to validate in php if you have a null, a string.empty, or a guid.empty.

I use the following code to check for guid.empty in php

```
function isGuidEmpty($my_guid_as_a_string) {
    // Assuming the guid is valid
    $retVal = false;
    $val = $array_sum(explode("-", $my_guid_as_a_string));

    if ($val == 0) {
        // Guid is empty
        $retVal = true;
 }

 return $retVal;
}
```

I know there are better ways using regular expressions, but this usually does the trick.